# bathroom switch and outlet

Tags: receptacle

my house is 43 years old and has a 15 amp gfci outlet and a switch to a light in a double gang box.  When I bought the house, nothing was said, but now i heard the code has change to 20 amp gfci.  does the gfci also have to be separate in a single gang box as well? What is the rule for preexisting homes before NEC codes change

Comment: You understand that you couldn't just change the receptacle to a 20 amp gfci, right? This would not increase the current available at the receptacle, but would allow the plugging in of a 20-A plug which would not be advisable or allowed by the code. You would have to change the breaker to 20-A and could only do that if the wires were large enough to allow that or you would rewire.

Comment: In our 45-year-old tract house the two bathrooms are wired with 12 AWG aluminum NM on one 15-A circuit. I originally put in a GFCI receptacle in the close one to the panel, but later changed to a GFCI breaker on that circuit. I had a reason for the change, but now can't remember it. I think the box with the GFCI receptacle was overfull of wires, given that the aluminum was pigtailed with copper. A neighbor who has the same setup has over-current breaker trips when visitors use hair dryers in both bathrooms at the same time.

Answer (score 2):

Codes are usually enforced only when work is newly done or significantly upgraded. You are almost never legally required to upgrade old work to modern code, though sometimes it's desirable for safety, convenience, or sellability.

Assuming you're not having trouble with the existing setup, and you have the proper GFCI and overcurrent protection, there is no reason to change. When you build your next bathroom, they'll dedicate a 20A circuit just to outlets, so you can your hair dryer and curling iron at the same time!